# Как заставить работать LESS?

Tags: css, less

Я присоединил файл с расширением less и затем (за ним) присоединил файл less.js (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cloudhead/less.js/master/dist/less-1.3.3.min.js). Но почему-то я не увидел сгенерированных стилей CSS. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2):

А так вы и не увидите сгенерированных стилей.
Есть два варианта:

- либо вы на клиентской стороне компилируете less (как сейчас пытаетесь), и тогда выполняете все рекомендации: стили подключаете с атрибутом rel="stylesheet/less", ну и, кстати, версию посвежее подключите: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/1.7.0/less.min.js;
- либо же компилируете при разработке. lessc style.less > style.css. А чтобы было удобнее, можно настроить какую-либо следилку. Для себя, например, я использую grunt-contrib-watch.

Answer (score 1):

Сгенерь отдельным компилятором
например http://koala-app.com/

он сразу генерит, налету, после сохранения less файла
а в html уже подключай сгенеренный css файл